# Realm passing selected category values

Tags: swift, realm

I have a task app that I am working on. users can create task and in turn create items under their categories. I am using realm as my data storage but I want to be able to pass some details from the selected category to the create items viewcontroller. I decided to print the selected category to the console but it prints nil and I dont know why. Below is my code.

```
class CategoryModel: Object {

    @objc dynamic var id = UUID().uuidString
    @objc dynamic var name: String = ""
    @objc dynamic var color: String = ""
    @objc dynamic var isCompleted = false

    let items = List<TodoListModel>()

    override static func primaryKey() -> String? {
        return "id"
    }
}
```

**Items VC**

```
 var selectedCategory: CategoryModel?

 override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        print("Selected Category: \(String(describing: selectedCategory))")
 }
```

I do not know why it keeps printing nil

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because you don't give it a value when you show the itemsVC

```
let item = ItemsVC()  // if VC is inside IB use self.storyboard?.instantiate.....
item.selectedCategory  = // set here or inside prepareForSegue if you use segues 
// here present
```

Comment: Hi if you could take a moment to help check this out https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52234687/saving-a-linked-object-to-realm-database-in-swift

Answer (score 1):

You can parse in this way;

Items VC

```
let realm = try! Realm()
var category:Results< CategoryModel>?

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
       loadCategory()
    }

    func loadCategory(){
        category = realm.objects(CategoryModel.self)
        //tableView.reloadData()  for example
    }

//category?[indexPath.row].name    for example using
```