# Saving a Linked object to Realm Database in swift

Tags: ios, swift, realm

I am trying to create a list item in a category after selecting the category but I when ever I click on the save button, nothing happens and the values dont get saved in the realm database. Below is my code  which is not working

```
func createTodoList(name: String, description: String, createdDate: Date, remiderDate: Date, isCompleted: Bool) -> Void {

        let item = TodoListVC()

        if let currentCategory = item.selectedCategory {

            do {
                try self.database.write {
                    let todoList = TodoListModel()
                    todoList.name = name
                    todoList.desc = description
                    todoList.createdDate = createdDate
                    todoList.isCompleted = false

                    currentCategory.items.append(todoList)
                }
            } catch {
                print("error items")
            }
        }
}
```

**Create VC**

```
@IBAction func saveBtn(sender: AnyObject) {

        TodoListFunctions.instance.createTodoList(name: name, description: description, createdDate: Date(), isCompleted: false)

        dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
```

further codes would be supplied based on request.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add the object inside write callback

```
self.database.add(todoList)
```

Comment: it does not get saved still. the add viewcontroller just get dismissed and the database does not get updated

Comment: sure that this **if let currentCategory = item.selectedCategory** is true ?? , can you verify whether the execution goes inside the try block ??

Comment: I fixed it. selected item was nil. I didnt set the value from the selection of the category. Thanks for the heads up

Comment: Hi, if you could help check this question out https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52238005/setting-usernotification-with-date-from-a-realm-database-swift